# Why is QGIS 2.14 automatically changing field type when saving layer?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, save

I'm  creating shapefiles with specific field types (i.e. ID: integer, NAME: String, CODE: integer, etc.) using QGIS 2.14.0.

When I save the layer using "right-click" - "save as" and load the newly saved layer in QGIS, all field types are changed to "string". I don't change any default parameters in the "save as" window.

Is it a bug or a common issue someone has already encountered ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update to a later version of 2.14.x (currently we are at 2.14.3), [this issue has already been fixed](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14411).